# Evaluate the limit $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{x_{1}^{2}x_{2}^2...x_{k}^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, inequality, convergence-divergence

We have the sequences $(x_{n})_{n\geq1}$$(y_{n})_{n\geq1}$ with positive real numbers. $x_{1}=\sqrt{2}$, $y_{1}=1$ and $y_{n}=y_{n-1}\cdot x_{n}^{2}-3$ for every $n\geq2$. We know the sequence $(y_{n})_{n\geq1}$ is bounded. Find $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{x_{1}^{2}x_{2}^2...x_{k}^2}$$
I tried rewriting $y_{n}$ only with terms from $(x_{n})_{n\geq1}$ but we get an ugly formula. I don't know exactly how we can we use the fact that $(y_{n})_{n\geq1}$ is bounded.

Comment: What is the context of this question? Is it from a contest?

Comment: The problem is not from a contest, it is from mathematical gazette from Romania.

Comment: There is something wrong, because with this setup $y_2 = 1 \cdot 2-3 = -1$, but $(y_n)_{n\geq 1}$ are supposed to be positive.

Comment: Sorry I wrote wrong the recursion I will edit.

Comment: I'm not sure that this helps, but since $x_n^{-2} = y_{n-1}/(y_n+3)$, you can rewrite your sum as $\frac 12 + \sum_{k=2}^n  \frac 12 \frac{y_1 \cdots y_{n-1}}{(y_2+3) \cdots (y_n+3)} = \frac 12 + \sum_{k=2}^n  \frac 12 \frac{1}{(1+3/y_2) \cdots (1+3/y_{n-1})(y_n+3)}$ which is almost a geometric series... At least it shows that your sum converges.

Comment: @mowzorn That issue is introduced by your edit, which was undone by Stefan. Otherwise, we can have $ x_i = 2 , i \neq 1$ and $ y_i = 1 \forall i$, where $y_i = 1 \times 2^2 - 3 = 1$ for $i > 1$. (And the only impact of $x_1$ is that it scales the final sum.)

Comment: I know, but I also don't know how to undo submitted edits, sorry for creating confusion.

Comment: You can make another edit to undo the submitted edit. No need to force rollback to the original version. (After which, delete the comment as it's no longer relevant)

Comment: The title of the question looks like a challenge to users. Better to rephrase it like "evaluate the limit..." and it should probably include some detail rather than just being generic.

Comment: I changed the title, thanks for the advice.

Comment: If $y_{n}$ is constant the value of the limit will be $2/3$ this looks like a nice result.

Answer (score 12):

Introduce an auxilary sequence $z_n = \frac{y_n}{y_n+3} \iff y_n = 3\frac{z_n}{1-z_n}$. For $i \ge 2$, we have

$$y_i = y_{i-1}x_i^2 -3
\implies \frac{1}{x_i^2} = \frac{y_{i-1}}{y_i+3} = 
\frac{3\frac{z_{i-1}}{1-z_{i-1}}}{
3\frac{z_i}{1-z_i} + 3} = z_{i-1}\frac{1-z_i}{1-z_{i-1}}
$$
Multiply from $i = 2$ to any $k \ge 2$, we get

$$\prod_{i=2}^k \frac{1}{x_i^2} 
= \frac{1-z_k}{1-z_1}\prod_{i=1}^{k-1}z_i 
= \frac{1}{1-z_1}\left(\prod_{i=1}^{k-1}z_i - \prod_{i=1}^{k}z_i\right)
$$
Summing from $k = 2$ to $n$, we get

$$\sum_{k=2}^n \prod_{i=2}^k \frac{1}{x_k^2}
= \frac1{1-z_1}\left(z_1 - \prod_{i=1}^n z_i\right)
$$
This leads to
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \prod_{i=1}^k \frac{1}{x_k^2}
= \frac{1}{x_1^2}\left( 1 + \sum_{k=2}^n \prod_{i=2}^k \frac{1}{x_k^2}\right) = \frac1{x_1^2(1-z_1)}\left(1 - \prod_{i=1}^n z_i\right)$$

If $y_n$ is bounded from above by $M$, then $z_n$ is bounded from above by $\frac{M}{M+3} < 1$.

As a result, $\prod\limits_{i=1}^n z_i \le \left(\frac{M}{M+3}\right)^n$ and hence converges to $0$ as $n \to \infty$.

From this, we can deduce
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}
\sum_{k=1}^n \prod_{i=1}^k \frac{1}{x_k^2}
= \frac1{x_1^2(1-z_1)} = \frac{y_1+3}{3x_1^2} = \frac23$$

Comment: Thank you so much! It is any way that we can prove $(y_{n})_{n\geq1}$ is constant?

Comment: @StefanSolomon You can't. Take $x_n^2 = \begin{cases}\frac{27}{5},&n = 2\\2, &n \text{ odd}\\ 3,& \text{ even}\end{cases},\quad$ you get $y_n = (1,\frac{12}{5},\frac95, \frac{12}{5}, \frac95, \cdots )$ which is periodic and the limit remain equals to $\frac23$.